# Conditionally choosing view templates based on data from HTML5 localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Run**

```
myApp.run(function(){
    if(!(window.localStorage.storage1)){
        window.localStorage.setItem('storage1', null);
});
```

**Home View**

```
<div ng-if="window.localStorage.storage1 == null"> 
    <!-- Show this part of the view , called Part 1-->
</div>

<div ng-if="window.localStorage.storage1 != null"> 
    <!-- Show this part of the view -->
</div>
```

**On transition to some `state` I update the `storage1` to `{"someKey" : "someValue"}`**

Now in the `home` view, when `storage1` is set to null (actually the string `"null"`) then `part1` of the view should be shown and when `storage1`'s value is updated to a dictionary data type then view `part2` should be shown. But it does not. I virtually tried everything. I compared `typeof`, cast it explicitly, changed the default value given to the `storage1` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Angular expressions are evaluated in the context of the scope. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

In the controller for the Home View you will need to set something in the scope based off of what is in localStorage, and then use that in your `ng-if` expression.

Comment: Oh god! I don't know why I was trying to type check an object which angular expressions did not have access to. May be I was frustrated and did not think what I was doing. Actually when I woke up today morning I came to know what I was doing. Came now to correct it. May be I should have taken a walk before asking it here.